# How to change an Azure Analytics Services database model without changes the data source with Tabular Object Model (TOM)

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssms, ssas-tabular, azure-analysis-services

I am using Azure Analytics Services to hold a database for each client, and each database is composed of the same table structure. The only difference is the data is specific to each client on each database. I also have a test database that I make changes to the model such as calculated columns, measures, and kpis in visual studio. What I want is to apply these model changes to all the other databases on Analysis Services without altering their data sources.

So far, I've been working with the Tabular Object Model (TOM) library in c# to write a script to accomplish this. This is a simplified version what I have so far:

```
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // 
        // Connect to the local default instance of Analysis Services 
        // 
        string ConnectionString = <connection string>;

        // 
        // The using syntax ensures the correct use of the 
        // Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular.Server object. 
        // 
        using (Server server = new Server())
        {
            server.Connect(ConnectionString);

            Database mainDatabase;
            Model mainModel = null;
            Database clientDatabase = null;

            //
            // Iterate through all databases on Analyis Services
            //
            foreach (Database db in server.Databases)
            {
                if (db.ID == "main")
                {
                    mainDatabase = db;
                    mainModel = mainDatabase.Model;
                }
                else if (db.ID == "clientDatabase")
                {
                    clientDatabase = db;
                }
            }

            mainModel.CopyTo(clientDatabase.Model);

           
            clientDatabase.Update(Microsoft.AnalysisServices.UpdateOptions.ExpandFull);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to close this console window.");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Where mainDatabase is where I update the model, and clientDatabase is where I want to copy the model to but keep the data source.

This code will update the model on clientDatabase, but it also changes the data source. I've tried then changing the data source back to the original in the code but have been unsuccessful. I've tried using ProviderDataSource() and a connection string, but haven't been able to make this work. Also, all the data sources are from sql server databases.

Any ideas on how to change this data source back to the original or how to copy just model without altering the data source?

[This is where I've gotten info on using the TOM library.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/tom/introduction-to-the-tabular-object-model-tom-in-analysis-services-amo?view=asallproducts-allversions)

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use either BISM Normalizer or Tabular Editor to create a deployment script that doesn't make any reference to the data sources.  When you then execute this against the AAS Models you will only update the other parts the model that you want to update.